# Verify step in proving Green's theorem (oriented 2-cells)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

One of the step in proving Green's theorem is:(from Advanced Calculus of Several Variables)
For every nice region that is the image of unit square $I^2$ under a suitable mapping.
 The set $D$ subset in $R^2$ is
called an oriented smooth 2-cell if there exists a one-to-one $C^1$ mapping $F:U \rightarrow R^2$ such that $F(I^2)=D$ and $I^2$ is a subset of open set $U$ 
and the Jacobian determinant of F is positive at each point of U.

So from Inverse function theorem we now that $F$ open sets send to open sets.

Otherwise, F will send point from $Int(I^2)$ to $Int(D)$.
But why F will send frontier of square $(I^2)$ to frontier of $D$ and keeping the positive orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is a frontier point of $I^2$ and $F(x)$ is not a frontier point of $D$, then there is an open set around $F(x)$ contained in $\mbox{Int } D$.  The inverse image of that open set has to contain $x$, but is in $\mbox{Int } I^2,$ contradiction.

Since the Jacobian is positive, we know the orientation is preserved.

Comment: Since the Jacobian is positive, we know the orientation is preserved.  Can you please explain me way this is true.

Comment: The Jacobian matrix is a linear map from $R^2$ to $R^2$ which (linearly) approximates the map $F$.  The det of a matrix $A$ tells what happens to the unit square under the map $x \rightarrow Ax$.  The det of $A$ is $\pm$ the area of the parallelogram which is the image of the unit square under this map.  In the domain, the acute angle from $i$ to $j$ is counterclockwise.  If the angle from $Ai$ to $Aj$ is also clockwise, the det is positive.  Otherwise it is negative.  To see this from the atomic level, you really just have to write down a system of two equations and see what happens.